# Authenticating dialog box in Linux environment using Selenium

Tags: linux, authentication, selenium, autoit

The Base URL in my Web Driver class asks for authentication for username and password. My Scripts run perfectly on Windows environment using AutoIT for authentication using the below mentioned code line.

```
    `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("data/chromedriver_win32.exe").getFile());`
```

But I need to run on Linux environment and I want to replace this server authentication in place of AutoIT.
I have googled it and I got the results that I can still run the scripts using wine but the results are not perfect. If anyone found solution for this kind of problem please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a secure approach, but would it help to put user name & password in the URL?

I mention it is not a secure way since it is for an automated test and you'd have to take safeguards to ensure who the viewing audience is, since you don't want security risks.

If your application typically challenges with htpassword box, you might want to see
http://community.sitepoint.com/t/sending-htpasswd-login-information-in-a-url/2586/2